# Solving a system of Laplace equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $u_0$ and $u_1$ to be smooth functions defined on $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, consider the following system of equations

$$\triangle u_1 = C_1(\partial_{ij}u_0),$$
$$\triangle u_0 = C_0u_1,$$

where $\partial_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}$ and $C_0,C_1$ are constants. The boundary of $\Omega$ is assumed to be smooth, and $u_0|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$ and $u_1|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$. My question is that if we can solve the system (in the sense of nonzero strong solutions) with the given boundary data?

First of all, it is very easy to see that  this system can be solved if $C_0=0$. Maybe it somehow suggests that we should assume $C_0$ small? In addition, we can also assume $\Omega$ is anything you want in order to see what happens first. In addition, one can put any conditions on $C_0$ and $C_1$, except for them to be 0.

Comment: Are you picking $i$ and $j$ or is that supposed to be the determinant of the Hessian?

Comment: @AHusain Let's fix $i,j$ for the moment. But it is ok to assume that it is the determinant of Hessian if that helps.

Comment: Of course there exists a solution, namely $u_0=u_1=0$. I assume what you want to know is whether the solution is unique. Without some conditions on $C_0$ and $C_1$ you cannot expect this, even in one dimension.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Actually, I'm looking for some nonzero solutions. It doesn't have to be unique though. On the other hand, one can pretty much put any conditions on $C_0$ and $C_1$, expect for them to be $0$. I suspect the smallness would help. But I don't know at this point.

Comment: Just a note that inserting the determinant of the Hessian in the first equation would make the system _fully non-linear_ making it MUCH more complicated than the linear system that you get by selecting some particular values of $i$ and $j$ or even taking linear combinations of such choices. So you would better have a very good reason if you want to involve the determinant of the Hessian here.

Comment: Equivalently you are solving $(\triangle)^2 u_0 = C_1 (\partial_{ij} u_0)$ (whatever the RHS means). Maybe you want to look into literature concerning the bilaplacian operator?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I believe that is the case. In fact, I have convinced that the RHS of the first equation is of the form $ a^{ij} \partial_{ij} u_0$ (Summation convention is used here, $a^{ij}$ are independent of $u_0, u_1$). So I want to see what happens if $i,j$ are fixed first.

Comment: @WillieWong I believe that this may work as well, but I don't know any good literature on bi-laplacian equations. It would be great if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Let me just make precise Michael Renardy's remark: Consider the case where $n = 1$, $\Omega = [0,1]$. If as you wrote the equations are linear, we can reduce the problem to $\triangle u_1 = C_0 C_1 u_1$. With the boundary conditions you get non-zero solutions for a discrete set of negative values for the produce $C_0 C_1$. As written your system depends highly on the properties of the coefficients; please pin them down first.

Comment: @WillieWong If $n=1$ and $\Omega = [0,1]$, the system can be reduced to $u_1'' = C u_1$, where $C = C_0 C_1$, which is a standard ODE. The constant $C_0$ is positive but it can be taken arbitrarily small, where as $C_1$ is negative.

Comment: "The constant $C_0$ is positive but it can be taken arbitrarily small." But that's the problem. If $C = C_0 C_1 > -\pi^2$ (in particular when $C_0$ arbitrarily small) there are no non-trivial solutions. But if $C = C_0 C_1 = -\pi^2$ you have $u_1 = \sin (\pi x)$. The existence of non-trivial solutions to your system in general would depend sensitively on the values of $C_0$ and $C_1$, and how they relate to the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on $\Omega$. So you need to be precise about what the constants should be and what values they can take.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you very much for the comments. I need to take a close look at those constants.